# Redirect to index.php to prevent duplicate content

Tags: nginx, redirect

I would like to redirect to index.php in url for seo reasons to prevent duplicate content without breaking the site.

https://www.example.com/index.php/fr/google [WORKS]

https://www.example.com/index.php/id/google [WORKS]

https://www.example.com/index.php - [NOT WORKING]

should redirect to

https://www.example.com/fr/google

https://www.example.com/id/google

https://www.example.com/

My nginx config looks as follows

```
location / {
        # Redirect index.php to root (prevent duplicate content)
        rewrite ^/(.*?)index\.php[^/] /$1? permanent;
        rewrite ^/(.*?)index\.php(?:/(.*))?$ /$1$2? permanent;
        
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
```

`https://www.example.com/index.php` is not getting redirect to `https://www.example.com/`

Comment: I test your nginx config then everything works fine. also `https://www.example.com/index.php` redirected to `https://www.example.com/`

Comment: @xirehat I have the exact config on my laravel website and its not working